# css !Important in WPF style

Tags: wpf

I have text block with MaxWidth="80" and want change on Style without remove MaxWidth="80"

the TextBlock  is at third party control
for sample:

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox" >
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>

        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <TextBox  FontSize="45" Foreground="Blue" Text="OH My God"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: You are talking about a textblock, but your code has only TextBox, are you missing some code here?

Comment: textbox or textBlock, no important

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Where is the 'MaxWidth' property here?

Comment: Yes is important, because they have different properties. And like Aakanksha said, your code does not correspond to your question.

Comment: What is your problem? Could you please describe it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the WPF there is a strict rule which property or style is used.

**Attribute has more power than a style.**

You can solve this by order:

- Define a default style with the property set as 100.
- Define an new style that is based on the default and override the property value for your control and apply newly created style to your TextBox.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure i'm answering what you asked, since, as other users pointed out, the question is not well written. But...

A setter within a style has less priority than setting the property directly on the instance of the object.

So, even though your style declares

```
<Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="80"/>
```

If you write your textblock/textbox like this

```
<TextBlock MaxWidth="100"/>
```

the 100 will prevail on the 80, thus the max width will be 100.